# Retrieve email from Microsoft Graph API using Mail ID

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In Microsoft Graph API, how do you retrieve a specific mail using the Id (Mail ID)?

This is what I tried :

```
$filter => "Id eq 'AQMkADYwZWEyZDQy...someRandomID'"
```

but the response I get is the `property id does not support filtering`

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The property 'Id' does not support filtering for [List messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

You should retrieve a specific mail using the Id (Mail ID) through [Get message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{Mail ID}
```